# How to extract dependent variable names from for-looped glms object to use as titles

Tags: r

I am making barplots of corresponding model coefficients derrived from lapply function applied to a for-looped multi-glm object. Take LWAniMoveSubDat to be any data set that makes for facile explication in code below:

```
models.LW <- list()

ivnames.LW <- paste(names(subset(LWAniMovSubDat[,c(1:6)], select = -c(4))), 
                    collapse = ' + ')
dvnames.LW <- paste(names(LWAniMovSubDat[7:17]), sep = ',') 

for (y in dvnames.LW){
  form <- as.formula(paste(y, "~", ivnames.LW))
  models.LW[[y]] <- glm(form, data = LWAniMovSubDat) 
}

for (var in models.LW) {
  dev.new()
  barplot(coef(var))
}
```

How do I add titles to the above barplots without getting things messed up. I tried the following and it does not work:

```
main = names(models.LW)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main = names(models.LW) doesn't work because that refers to the names of all of the models. If you change your barplot code as follows, where you iterate through the names of the models and then reference the models based on those names, it should work.

```
for (var in names(models.LW)){
   dev.new()
   barplot(coef(models.LW[var][[1]]), main = var)
}
```